# Math operation on list in bash

Tags: bash, list, math

I have a list of numbers in an list in bash:

```
bb=" 1 3 6 7 12 14 16 21 27 29 32 35 39 42"
```

I want to apply mathematical operations on it (add/subtract/divide/multiply one number to each term of this list). How can I do this using bash?

Example using `bb` introduced before:

- add 1 to each number, result: `2 4 7 8 13 15 17 22 28 30 33 36 40 43`
- multiply by 5: `5 15 30 35 60 70 80 105 135 ...`

I tried this: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=1+$i}}END{print $0}' <<< $bb` but `$0` returns only the original record and not the modified one.

Comment: I don't really know how I can do this...

Comment: What would the result of the operation be? Can you show a full example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition through awk,

```
$ bb=" 1 3 6 7 12 14 16 21 27 29 32 35 39 42"
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=1+$i}}1' <<< $bb
2 4 7 8 13 15 17 22 28 30 33 36 40 43
```

Multiplication

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=5*$i}}1' <<< $bb
5 15 30 35 60 70 80 105 135 145 160 175 195 210
```

Comment: Thank you ! The added `1` the end is just for showing the result?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop:

```
for num in $bb ; do
    results+=( $(( num + 1 )) )
  # results+=( $(( num * 5 )) )
done
echo "${results[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you *could* use bash arithmetic operations, after writing a bash function, that you feed in a bash feed with elements of your list, which you might split with a lot of tools.

Seriously, though, bash is not an arithmetic tool. On modern systems, there's a plethora of capable scripting languages available, and there's little reason not to use them.

For example:

```
 python -c "print sum([int(substring) for substring in '$bb'.split(' ')])"
```

if you want to use a python one-liner; you could of course just write a python program and use the incredible amount of libraries. I find myself regularly starting off something as a shell script and then figuring out that (intentional) calls to other executables make up a small part of code, and most of the things can be better done in a "real" language, just to then rewrite stuff in less lines of python.

EDIT: you want to count pages in PDFs:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import poppler
doc = poppler.document_new_from_file("file:///home/guuk/document.pdf","")
print doc.get_n_pages()
```

Comment: I agree with you but currently I am writing a very small and simple script for counting some pages in a pdf file. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: That sounds even more like it would be easier in python than bash :D

Comment: :D maybe maybe but I am not very familiar with python